# Default preselected values for Windows Forms DatagridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I'm currently trying to implement a DatagriView in Windows Forms with preselected and default values.

Basically the first column will have constants as values, which won't change at all. Row 2 and 3 will get their values from Objects and row 4 should have a Combobox with a preselected default value.

Here is an image of what I mean:
[image: DatagridView example]

I managed to create the Datagridview and to add 2 values into the Combobox but the combobox won't show the first value as selected.
I also don't know how to have constant values in the first column.

Comment: share the code where you create combox box

Comment: There is no code. I have created it with the designer

Comment: Do you mean that the first Column is not *editable* (i.e., it's `ReadOnly`)? Did you set the `DataPropertyName` of the fourth Column to the name of the corresponding Column in the DataSource? Did you set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the ComboBoxColumn? -- You forgot to mention what the DataSource of the DGV is, whether you bind it a Design-Time or Run-Time, whether some Columns are auto-generated while others are added in the Designer etc.